# OK to create MySQL data tables in production environment

Tags: mysql, performance, datatables

I need to create a `MySQL tempory table` in a production environment. The table could contain a column with more than half a million records at most. Usually, it will be around several thousands of record.

I have several questions here

1. Is it OK to create tempory tables in production DB server
   environments
2. What could be the performance impact with this within the same MySQL client session
3. Will I be able to reduce the performance impact If I store data in the disc rather than the memory
4. Any elegent solutions instead of this

Comment: 1) Yes in principal. 2) You would have to try it your system/server is probably setup differently to mine. 3) Memory (if you have enough) would probably be quicker 4) Difficult to suggest a solution to a problem you do not actually tell us about

Comment: How do you  mean is it ok you will need to discuss with your DBA.

Comment: Of course, it would be a good idea to test this out on your Development Server and then your UAT Server first. That would help you get a feeling for how it is affecting other workloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, there can be no other answer than "it depends", so the answer can only be general.

1. Applications do create temporary tables when they need them. It is a normal practice and one of the reasons for existence of temporary tables. MySQL also creates them internally for some operations.
2. Depends on the current workload of the server and its capabilities (CPU/RAM/HDD).
3. Unlikely. Probably best bet is to allow MySQL manage them; it automatically converts temporary memory tables to disk tables, when becoming low on memory ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-temporary-tablespace.html )
4. Depends on the specifics of your problem. How often will the tables be created and how long will they persist. Temporary table itself could be argued to be an elegant solution in that it allows you to keep temporary data on one side and avoid extra data copying to/from processing application.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you're not providing a lot of context, so "it depends".

I very general terms, creating tables and storing data in them is what relational database are designed to do. Whether it's one row or millions, relational databases *love* data, and are really good at optimizing storage and access - it's very unlikely you can do better than MySQL at this.

However...all servers are - to an extent - resource constrained. Production servers typically have weird, unpredictable usage patterns; month-end reconciliation runs, sudden bursts of activity from one department or user type, reporting runs on Friday afternoons, the real world doesn't seem to run to a predictable schedule.

Again, in very general terms, database servers tend to have "hockey stick" performance curves - as long as you don't hit some resource bottleneck, response times go up broadly in relation to usage. Then when you hit a bottleneck (typically CPU, RAM or disk access), you see an upward inflection with response times increasing dramatically.

If your production server is close to reaching that bottleneck point during one of the real world's unpredictable peak, then anything you add to that server (including your temporary table) could trigger the inflection point. So, ask someone who understands the production environment how heavily loaded the production server is at peak times.

The next concern is that creating and storing data is usually not a performance problem - but querying the data can be (and slow-running queries tie up a lot of resources which can affect other processes and users). I'm guessing you're not just storing the data, you're doing something with it; if that is slow, or resource intensive, it could have a measurable impact. Tune and optimize the queries (on a separate environment!), make sure your EXPLAIN shows you're using indexes for everything, and the queries return in milliseconds, and you're *probably* okay.

Is there a more elegant solution? Yes, you can move the data to a separate "reporting" server, where you can do whatever processing your temporary table supports.